# How can i find the Data Usage on Per Application Basis?

Tags: android

hi i am workig on Traffic Application in Android which show the data recived and Sent By the Android Device.

how can i fetch the recived and Sent Data for a patucular time like how can i fetch last 24 hrs recived and sent data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TrafficStats` to determine bandwidth usage per-UID, which roughly corresponds to per-app.

Comment: yes you are right ,but i want to determine the last 24 hr. data used by My Android device .working with time ??
That is the Actual Problem .

Comment: @AkhilSoni: Examine `TrafficStats` every 24 hours, then.

Comment: not getting your meaning sorry .and not get any example after a lot of search .

Comment: i want to show those installed application on the android ListView that used the internet data .how can i do that ??